# Learn GCD now and can't find any example of QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT usage

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I found many examples of any global queue usage but couldn't find any example of QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT usage. 
Can someone provide any info when we have to use it.

I just know that it's priority is lower that QOS_USER_INITIATED (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH) and higher that QOS_CLASS_UTILITY (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW).

Thank you for any explanation!

Comment: What do you mean by "usage"?  If it's a priority then it will be used when appropriate, which I assume will vary wildly, from app to app.

Comment: Check out wwdc session 716: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/716/

Comment: @TomasCamin Thank you! Definitely I will!